# filter and replace array state using setState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im currently building an React app that would take user input, loop through and filter array data that contain that input and change another field of that same data. However, when I use the setState, it shows that it isn't working and i cannot change the field. Another problem I had is that when I try to display the data in a table using .map, it would show error when I use setState to change the data. Any lead on how to make this work is appreciated.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

This is how I fetch data from my database.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/edit").then(res => {
        if(res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        }
    })
    .then(jsonRes => setData(jsonRes))
},[])
```

This is my filter function that activate on button click. the q is the user input, the multiple console.log is used to check whether each step is working, and while each step seems to work and console.log(copyData[i]) shows disired field being replaced, it doesn't work after I put it in setData.

```
 const filter = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(q)
  const pattern = new RegExp("\\b"+q+"\\b", "ig")
  console.log(pattern)
  console.log(data.length)
  for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1){
      console.log(data[i])
      let copyData = {...data}
      console.log(copyData)
      let replaceData = {
        ...copyData[i],
        vector: 'testing filter'
      }
      console.log(replaceData)
      copyData[i]=replaceData
      console.log(copyData[i])
      setData(copyData)
    }
  }
}
```

This is my table which works at first, but after setData, it would error and say data.map is not a function

```
 <table className="content-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Species</th>
            <th>Vector</th>
            <th>Agent</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {data.map(data=> 
        <tbody>
        
        <tr key={data._id} data-item={data} >
            <td  data-title="name">{data.diseaseName}</td>
            <td  data-title="species">{data.species}</td>
            <td  data-title="vector">{data.vector}</td>
            <td  data-title="agent">{data.agent}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        )}
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this line in your filter function `let copyData = {...data}`. `data` is an array but you're copying it into an object. This works just fine. The object keys will be the array indexes (0, 1, 2...). But object's do not have the array methods `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc. This is why you see the error "data.map is not a function."

Change `let copyData = {...data}`
to `let copyData = [...data]`

Update - Additional thoughts

1. Here's how I would write your filter method. You want to avoid calling `setData` from within the for loop. That will cause a re-render on every iteration. Rather, build the new data array and then call `setData` once.

```
const filter = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const pattern = new RegExp("\\b"+q+"\\b", "ig");
  const newData = data
    .filter(d => d.diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1))
    .map(d => ({ ...d, vector: 'testing filter' }));
  setData(newData);
}
```

2. `setData` could also be called like this (the `prevInput` you mentioned in your comments, I think): `setData(prev => prev.filter(d => d.diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1))`

This would be useful if you were to wrap you filter method in `useCallback`.

```
const filter = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const pattern = new RegExp("\\b"+q+"\\b", "ig");
  setData(prev => prev.filter(d => d.diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1));
}, [q]);
```

This way, `data` does not need to be listed in the dependency array and the filter function does not need to be re-created as often.

3. In general, I would not change the original data array but create a derived value for the filtered array with `useMemo`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [q, setQ] = useState('');

const filteredData = useMemo(() => {
  const pattern = new RegExp("\\b"+q+"\\b", "ig");
  return data.filter(d => d.diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1));
}, [data, q]);
```

This way, there is no need to imperatively call the filter function. Everything is kept in sync, and you can reference the original & filtered arrays as needed.

Comment: Hey thanks for this correction, this is actually all it took, however now I have another problem, which is when the loop is going, it only replace the last data that it matches, I assume this is because it's taking old data to replace which hasn't been updated to when the loop is happening and previous match has already been replaced yet. I have a slight idea that I can use prevInput to fix this, but Im not sure how, can you help me with this?

Comment: Added some alternative implementations that I think might help.

Comment: Thankyou so much for all the suggestions! It gave me a lot of ideas on how to continue my project, however, I cannot use the filter method you used in your example. This is because  I want to allow the user to be able to do multiple filters and reverse a search. My method of doing that is increase or decrease a field with a score each time a data match the input or the user delete the filter, and use another filter to display data that match the number of overall filters(sorry if this is confusing) therefore I need all the data intact. Thats why Im using the loop to only edit once that matches

Comment: I will mark this as solved, but If you have any other idea you want to suggest, I will gladly hear how you would implement it, expecithally how I can use make my current method work as it is the only way I can think of. Thanks.

Comment: This is how I tried to do it with my idea of prevData but it isn't woorking. ```setData( (prevData) => ({
        data: [
           [...prevData],
           {
             ...prevData[i],
           matched: ++
           }
        ]
      }))```

Comment: my data is structure is 
```const [data, setData] = useState  ({
        diseaseName: '',
        species: '',
        vector: '',
        vectorName: '',
        agent: '',
        agentName: '',
        symptoms: ''
        matched: 0
    })```
There are many data each with the set fields. I tried to iterate data so the array contain only the chosen data's fields, then edit the field, am I going in the right direction?

Comment: you're initializing data (`useState({ diseaseName: ''... })` ) as an object not an array. So treating `prevData` as an array later is incorrect. If you want to merge a new object with the previous you can call setData like `setData(prev => ({ ...prev, ...newData })`

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what the shape of your data is so it's entirely possible this is way off, but my bet is that your problem is in this for loop here

```
  for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1){
      console.log(data[i])
      let copyData = {...data}
      console.log(copyData)
      let replaceData = {
        ...copyData[i],
        vector: 'testing filter'
      }
      console.log(replaceData)
      copyData[i]=replaceData
      console.log(copyData[i])
      setData(copyData)
    }
  }
```

can you instead do a [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the data and then call setData? doing it in the for loop could cause additional renders and the filter should be safely returning an array something like

```
const filteredData = data.filter((disease) => disease.diseaseName.search(pattern) > -1)
setData(filteredData)
```

also from a html, accessibility standpoint you dont really want to map your data to multiple `tbody` tags

```
    <tbody>
     {data.map(data=>(
        <tr key={data._id} data-item={data} >
          <td  data-title="name">{data.diseaseName}</td>
          <td  data-title="species">{data.species}</td>
          <td  data-title="vector">{data.vector}</td>
          <td  data-title="agent">{data.agent}</td>
        </tr>
       )
     )}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for this suggestion, I was actually going for this method before I tried the loop. However for my app, I want to allow the user to be able to do multiple filters and reverse a search. My method of doing that is increase or decrease a field with a score each time a data match the input or the user delete the filter, and use another filter to display data that match the number of overall filters(sorry if this is confusing) therefore I need all the data intact.The method you provided was way cleaner so if you have any idea how to implement it in my app, please let me know